# Prove in Zero Knowledge the execution of a function

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Given a function:

$$Y = a * b$$

Is there a way to prove in zero knowledge that a value $Y$ was gotten, without revealing $a$ and $b$?  Alternatively, that we have knowledge of $a$ and $b$ such that their product equals $Y$.

public : $Y$

private: $a$,$b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you describe is an example of a zero-knowledge proof.

ZKP systems such as [libSNARK](https://github.com/scipr-lab/libsnark), [libSTARK](https://github.com/elibensasson/libSTARK), [pepper-project](https://github.com/pepper-project/pequin), etc. can help the prover generate a proof that he/she knows private $a$ and $b$ such that $Y = a * b$ and then a verifier can check that the computation was done correctly without ever knowing $a$ and $b$.

What you describe is the knowledge-of-factorization example and I recently implemented that in the pepper-project [here](https://github.com/pepper-project/pequin/blob/master/pepper/apps/prover_knows_factorization.c).

Comment: What about Y = a / b ?

Comment: It is same logic with a different operator.

Comment: The lib seems to be focussed around zksnarks, is there any way to use it without the verification/proving keys?

Comment: If I wanted multiple people to verify a computation, I would need multiple keys?

Comment: The keys are generated per program, not per verifier. libSTARK does not use prover/verifier keys.